# cv2 match and find out box shape and corner

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use cv2 to match the best squares shape and calculate the products' height and width.

However, I have found many examples in which I cannot solve my problem using findcontour, edge line etc.

Here is my Image and code.

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
ret, t = cv2.threshold(img, 40, 200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

plt.imshow(t)
```

[image: Threshold_Image]

Also, I tried

```
edge = cv2.Canny(t, 70, 150)
edge = cv2.dilate(edge, None, iterations = 1)
edge = cv2.erode(edge, None, iterations = 1)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image: Edge Detection Image]

This product is based on box and some parts are attached on that box.
I want to extract exactly out box shape and get h, w...

Please share your comments and idea..

**[EDIT]**

The below image is the one of the raw data.

[image]

Comment: input data is required. screenshots of matplotlib plots are not usable data. please review [mre]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for your comments. I forgot to upload the original image data. I uploaded the sample.